# Обязательные поля в DTO

Tags: java, json

У нас есть DTO, у которого только одно поле. Это поле само POJO. И у DTO сеттеры и геттеры которые по факту устанавливают все на POJO и берут с нее. Повесить аннотации на POJO нельзя. Как в таком случае можно определить какой параметр не передали в запросе? Используется Jackson. Полей на POJO очень много.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, пример кода, чтобы было понятно, о чем речь.

Comment: проверить все на null не вариант? если уж сосем много поле - через reflection пройтись по всем полям